# Can I set Manage stock at website level?

Tags: multi-website, cataloginventory, magento2.4.0

I have question regarding inventory management.

I do not want to use multi source inventory for our magento 2.4.0 store.

Now we are going to convert multi website with different quantities for same product so is there any way to do manage different quantitates for multi website without MSI?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is not a great way to make this happen without writing some pretty formidable plugin logic. I had a simular problem at my old company where we needed to turn off MSI for performance reasons, but retain stock status on a per website level.

What we ended up doing was creating a plugin hook that if a product quanity was at -1 or lower, it would trigger a out-of-stock message on certain storefronts, but not others (all product were technically "in stock" from a Magento viewpoint). Technically specking, it could be possible to hack something similar with the `getStockQty()` function in the Catalog_Inventory module, but I would highly recommend against such actions it goes against the natural flow of Magento and could break in future updates as well.